# Upload image worked on local but not on server

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I had to upload image on server. I have this PHP code:

```
<?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
    if(isset($_FILES['photo'])){

        //Getting actual file name
        $name = $_FILES['photo']['name'];

        //Getting temporary file name stored in php tmp folder
        $tmp_name = $_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'];

        //Path to store files on server
        $path = 'images/testimonial/';

        //checking file available or not
        if(!empty($name)){
            //Moving file to temporary location to upload path
            move_uploaded_file($tmp_name,$path.$name);

            //Displaying success message
            echo "Upload successfully";
        }else{
            //If file not selected displaying a message to choose a file
            echo "Please choose a file";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

My AJAX code:

```
$('#uploadImage').submit(function(e){

    //Preventing the default behavior of the form
    //Because of this line the form will do nothing i.e will not refresh or redirect the page
    e.preventDefault();

    //Creating an ajax method
    $.ajax({

        //Getting the url of the uploadphp from action attr of form
        //this means currently selected element which is our form
        url: $(this).attr('action'),

        //For file upload we use post requestd
        type: "POST",

        //Creating data from form
        data: new FormData(this),

        //Setting these to false because we are sending a multipart request
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function(data){
            //If the request is successfull we will get the scripts output in data variable
            //Showing the result in our html element
            $('#msg').html(data);
        },
        error: function(){}
    });
});
```

My HTML code:

```
<form id='uploadImage' action='ajaxupload.php' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
    <input id="im2" type="file" name='photo' class="dropify-fr" data-default-file="" data-max-file-size="200K" />
    <button>Upload</button>
</form>
```

It works fine in local and add the image in the specific folder but on server I get "upload successfully" without getting the image in the folder. Who have an idea please what's wrong?

Comment: Mabe the folder structure does not exist on your server. Furthermore `move_uploaded_file` returns a `bool` (see http://php.net/manual/de/function.move-uploaded-file.php), so you could/should check if the function succeeds.

Comment: Best to use an absolute path either using `__DIR__` or `dirname(__FILE__)` - Also ensure the directory is writable.

Comment: thanks @mpf82 but if there is problem with move_uploaded_file why in local it works ?

Comment: who can help me please i tried many code and as always work in local but not on remote server i can't know where is the problem   the folder structure exist on server and it is writable